# How fast is the build-in function SHGetValueA function (shlwapi.h) in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, caching, registry

I have been in doubt about what should be a better approach:

1. To cache the registry and use it later (I won't be doing it multiple times).
2. To run this function when needed (if it is fast)

How can I measure the speed of this function?

```
int ReadUACRegistryKey(LPCWSTR key)
{
    LPCWSTR pszSubKey, pszValue = key;
    const std::wstring sPath = L"XXXXXXXXXXX";

    pszSubKey = sSearchPattern.c_str();
    DWORD dwType = 0;
    DWORD dwValue = 0;
    DWORD dwValueSize = sizeof(dwValue);

    int retval = SHGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, pszSubKey, key, &dwType, &dwValue, &dwValueSize);
    if (retval != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        Trace(TRACE_ERROR, _T("ERROR: Failed to retrieve Registry setting and check Input_Image format."));
    }

    return dwValue;
}
```

Comment: Caching the whole registry database make not much sense as it can be really huge on some machine. `SHGetValue` is a system function do a system call (ie. syscall) internally. Syscalls are generally pretty expensive but it can be seen as cheap regarding your expectation. Syscalls generally takes at least few microseconds. Access to the registry can be seen as accessing files except it is simpler internally so certainly faster. I also expect the OS to cache values for sake of performance. THus, it should take from a microsecond to the speed of an IO seek+read (few dozens of ms on a slow HDD).

Comment: "*How can I measure the speed of this function?*" - by **profiling** your code, the same way you time the speed of anything else.

Comment: @JérômeRichard That makes sense. I was just talking about cashing one key value from a particular registry path, which I need(it might be used later, so I wanted to cache it beforehand). But yes, your suggestion makes sense that it is pretty fast, so there is no need to do it now.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Okay. This thing is, I don't want my system-specific timing. This code will be run on computers and non-computer devices with windows installed. Hence, I need to get the function speed irrespective of my system.

Comment: @SumitSahu so just write some code to clock how long the function actually takes to run, and then log that value somewhere you can see it.